# Excel data to Word-Template via Search and Replace - Multiple Documents

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, macros

I have no experience in Word- or Excel-Macros, but I want to import excel data into several word-files, each contain the same content. (I thought this task could not be so complicated after all, and I tried to complete it via the formletter-function, but when I failed, I realized that indeed it is much more complicated than I thought. Then I thought, maybe this is the right place to ask for adivce...).

Example Data (Excel data):

```
    Varname   Value
    Var1      2
    Var2      3
    Var3      0.5
    ...
```

Example Data (Word template)

```
    The following treats the topic on "Varname". Its Value is "Value".
```

So in the End it should look like:

```
    The following treats the topic Var1. Its Value is 2. (saved as Var1.doc or even better Var1.txt, but *.doc would be ok for the beginning!)
    The following treats the topic Var2. Its value is 3. (saved as Var2.doc)
    The following treats the topic Var3. Its value is 0.5. (saved as Var3.doc)
   ...
```

Although the actual text is much more complicated and should not be part of the code itself. So I thought the best solution must be something with "find" and "Replace". Since I am completely new to macros in Word/Excel, I couldn't find out how to implement the Excel data for the "Replace"-function.

```
    ' Replace-Excel-Data-Macro
    '
    '
        Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = """Varname"""
            .Replacement.Text = "**???**"
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = """Value"""
            .Replacement.Text = "**???**"
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End Sub
```

I am sorry if this question has been asked before, I couldn't find proper help until now, maybe due to my very limited knowledge of this macro-stuff.. Many thanks for your comments in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Mail Merge in Winword to do such tasks simply.

You fill your template from the data source: execl/database/whatever your data.

in your template you define the field name from your data source.

For example, your template look like:

```
The following treats the topic on <<Varname>> Its Value is <<Value>>
```

Using the wizard:

in the wizard you define your template with fields , data source

On the Mailings tab, click Start Mail Merge, and then click Step by
   Step Mail Merge Wizard.

follow these steps from the tutorial:

[How to use mail merge to create form letters in Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/294683)

Comment: my answer is a little late, but still thank you! In the end I did it exactly this way :)